# Cakephp 4.0.1 not able to remove cookie

Tags: cookies, cakephp-4.x

```
use Cake\Http\Cookie\Cookie; 

use Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection;

$cookieCollection=$this->request->getCookieCollection();

$cookieCollection1 = $cookieCollection->remove(‘remember_meqq’);

$this->response = $this->response->withCookieCollection($cookieCollection1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, somehow removing cookie from a CookieCollection won't work for me too.
But, there is an alternative way. You can just set the cookie value to an empty string & it will be removed.

```
$cookies = $this->request->getCookieCollection();
$this->response = $this->response->withCookieCollection($cookies)
                ->withCookie(Cookie::create('remember_meqq', ''));
```